# How to rake database to Heroku on cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, database-migration, cloud9-ide

I'm a noobie to Heroku, Github and RoR, so this week I'm stumbling through it.

I have a DB on Git and I'd like to clone it and push it to my Heroku App via Cloud9 (I'm working on a chromebook)

I can't use the commands in the C9 terminal:

```
    heroku run rake db:migrate
    heroku restart
```

tl;dr: How do I migrate a git DB to a Heroku app's Database from Cloud9?

oh, and also: If I'm using the wrong terminology, just let me know how bad of a person I am and correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst Cloud9 supports git deployments you can't run the commands that you need to via their console to manage your application. You will need to use the heroku gem locally to manage your application which isn't going to be possible on a Chrome book. Your best option will be use use a VPS server somewhere that you can SSH into (assuming that's possible) to work via.

Comment: Correct. The hosted version of Cloud9 doesn't come with the Heroku binaries installed. You can use the Heroku API for it (by writing a node.js script that does this), if they offer such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Heroku toolbelt via c9pm (Cloud9 Package Manager):

```
c9pm install heroku
```

Then you have to login into your Heroku account and perform the *db:migrate*.
Also I suggest to run it detached with this line:

```
heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

I couldn't perform a normal rake from C9. I always have to run it detached to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has an api. You may need to make calls against it if you cant install the heroku ruby gem. Maybe someone has done this try google.

Comment: I have been trying google for the past 6~ hours... no help. I don't get why the DB isn't being created. Doesn't help that I'm new to Rails...

Answer (score 0):

If my previous answer doesn't work for you, because you can't install the *Heroku Toolbelt* in C9. You could run *rake* to perform the *migrate* in your production (Heroku) environment like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

This will use the *database.yml* from your **local repository** (in C9) to update the Heroku (production) DB.

I do not recommended this practice because you could have another DB definitions in the Heroku repository from previous *commits/pushes*, but solves the problem.